# Can't access $scope variable in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-scope, promise

In my controller I call a factory that returns a JSON object as such:

```
function getData() {
    trainDataFactory.getData()
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.dataList = data;
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load data: ' + error.message;
        });
}
```

I am then able to access $scope.dataList in the view like so (which works):

```
{{ dataList[0].UnitNumber }}
```

But I want to access this same variable in the controller however it won't work - angular just breaks.

I try this at the start of the controller:

```
init();
function init() {
    getData();

    console.log($scope.dataList[0].UnitNumber);

    $scope.firstDataListItem = $scope.dataList[0].UnitNumber;
}
```

getData() is called so I don't see why $scope.dataList is unavailable??

Comment: Can you post the whole controller? You're probably doing something wrong with the inclusion of the $scope element and reaching the getData() method from the inner scope of the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data retrieval in `getData()` is going to execute *asynchronously*. It's not going to be available the moment `getData()` is done executing.

You need to make use of promises:

```
function getData() {
    return trainDataFactory.getData()
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        throw new Error('Unable to load data: ' + error.message);
    });
}

function init() {    
    getData().then(function (data) {
        $scope.dataList = data;
        console.log(data[0].UnitNumber);
        $scope.firstDataListItem = data[0].UnitNumber;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        $scope.status = error.message;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. So, when working asynchronously the then statement is important to access the data directly after retrieving it?

Comment: Also, does this mean to use dataList you must access it either in getData().then(function (data) { } or outside of the init() function?

Comment: @JakkyD Yes, promises and the `then()` method are very important for asynchronous tasks. I recommend reading [this book](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/async%20%26%20performance) when you have the time. I don't entirely understand your second question, but generally, you should be doing asyncrhonous tasks inside a `then()` handler _somewhere_.